# Increase line height based on the x distance

Tags: javascript, math

I have 4 lines and want to increase the height by 5 px but based on the x distance. It will be simple if the x distance have the same value but in my case it can be different.
For example if the x distance are so:

```
line.x: 50, 80, 110, 130
line.y: 20, 20, 20, 20
```

I could do

```
line.x: 50, 80, 110, 130
line.height: 20, 25, 30, 35
```

But how I can do the math when the x distance is so:

```
line.x: 50, 80, 95, 130
```

EDIT: Here is an example image:
[image]

Comment: `y = m * x + b` ?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms can you please explain the "y = m * x + b" a few more. I have not so good math experience :)

Comment: Your question is flawed. You just can’t increase Y by 5 for any X value to get what you want on a line. What you want is a line equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want an equation of a line that rises 15 units between `line.x[0]` and `line.x[3]`. If so, the following should work:

```
let line_x = [50,80,95,130];
let m = 15/(line_x[3]-line_x[0]);
line_y = line_x.map(x => m*(x-line_x[0]) + 20);
console.log(line_y);
//[ 20, 25.625, 28.4375, 35 ]
```

In simplified notation, the key step is calculating `y` as `y = m(x-x[0]) + 20` where `m = 15/(x[3]-x[0])` (which is a simple `slope = rise/run` calculation).

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to assign an array to line_x? I try that but it work's not (undefined error). var arr = [50, 80, 95, 130];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let line_x = [ arr[i] ];
  let m = 15/(line_x[line_x.length-1]-line_x[0]);
  line_y = line_x.map(x => m*(x-line_x[0]) + 20);
}
alert(line_y[1]);

Comment: @JCss  If you have an array named `arr` and want to assign a copy of it to `line_x` then you could use `let line_x = [...arr]` (with `...` being JavaScript's relatively new *spread operator*)

Comment: John Coleman I try that but this also not work's. Please see here: https://js.do/code/292968

Comment: @JCss Not quite clear what you are trying to do with the loop. Perhaps you want `let line_x = arr.slice(0,i);` in the body of the loop?

Comment: I solved it. I had some arrays, but with your math assistance, I did it the way I wanted. I appreciate your help very much Mr. Coleman. This problem had occupied me some time before :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that would allow you to change the angle as necessary, while defaulting to your current "4px over, 5px down" approach. You could also add a constant "start height" to all results if you didn't want it directly tied to x (i.e. so that at x= 0, it doesn't have to have a height of 0 too)

```js
function lineHeight(x, tareX = 0, initialHeight = 0, run = 4, rise = 5) {
  return (x - tareX) / run * rise + initialHeight;
}

const lines = [
  {
    x: 50,
  },
  {
    x: 80,
  },
  {
    x: 110,
  },
  {
    x: 130,
  },
];

lines.forEach(line => line.height = lineHeight(line.x, 50, 20));
console.log(lines);
```